# How do I make n-grams in python 3?

Tags: python-3.x

I am having a bit of a problem, I know that in python versions lower than three, you could import ngram from a library and just use it there.
But I can't figure out how to do it in python 3, so I've been trying to simulate them as follows:

```
def compute_ngrams(toks, n=2):
     d={}
     l=list(range(len(toks)-(n-1)))
     b=[]
     c=[]
     i=0
     while i < len(toks)-(n-1):
          if toks[i] in d:
                 l = toks[i],toks[i+1],
                 d[toks[i]]=[l]
          else:
                 l=(toks[i+1]),
                 d[toks[i]]=[l]
     i=i+1
print(d)
return d
```

The print(d) is only there to gauge what my output looks like, and I am having two errors:

(1)  My output is as such:

```
   {'i': [('really',)], 'really': [('really', 'like')], 'like': [('cake.',)]}
```

and (2) I am trying to have the code produce this output:

```
 {'i': [('really',)], 'like': [('cake.',)], 'really': [('really',), ('like',)]})
```

What I am trying to do is:
Select a random key and use it as the start token of the passage to serve as the current token for the next step.

Select a random tuple from the list associated with the current token and append the sequence to the passage. The last token of the selected sequence will be the new current token.

If the current token is a key in the dictionary then simply repeat step 2, otherwise select another random key from the dictionary as the current token and append it to the passage before repeating step 2.

I have tried to start the sequence off by first making a list, each slot containing one of the words, or tokens, and going from there, but this is the only way I was able to generate an output that Looked KIND OF similar, and ran.